# Room database rewrites values with the same id

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-room

I work with the room database (many-to-many relationship). I try to save the list of cast into a table. But the database sees that I insert cast with the same id (movie id) and just rewrites the value. Any idea how to correct it?

I insert a list with the help of the following query:

```
   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
   suspend fun insertCast (cast: List <CastDbModel>)
```

[image]

But when I try to get the data I get the last data that was inseted.

```
   @Transaction
   @Query("select * FROM `cast` WHERE id = :id")
   fun getAllCastAssociatedWithMovie(id: Int): List<CastDbModel>
```

[image]

```
@Entity(tableName = "movie")
data class MovieDbModel(
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
   val id: Int,
   val poster_path: String,
   val overview: String,
   val title: String)

@Entity(tableName = "cast")
@TypeConverters(CastConverter::class)
data class CastDbModel(
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
   val id : Int,
   val cast: Cast
)

data class Cast(
   val name: String,
   val profile_path: String?,
   val character: String
)
data class MovieWithListOfCast(
   @Embedded /* The parent */
   val movie: CastDbModel,
   @Relation(
       entity = CastDbModel::class, /* The class of the related table(entity) (the children)*/
       parentColumn = "id", /* The column in the @Embedded class (parent) that is referenced/mapped to */
       entityColumn = "id", /* The column in the @Relation class (child) that is referenced (many-many) or references the parent (one(parent)-many(children)) */
       /* For the mapping table */
       associateBy = Junction(
           value = MovieCastCrossRef::class, /* The class of the mapping table */
           parentColumn = "movieIdMap", /* the column in the mapping table that maps/references the parent (@Embedded) */
           entityColumn = "castIdMap" /* the column in the mapping table that maps/references the child (@Relation) */
       )
   )
   val castList: List<CastDbModel>
)

@Entity(
   tableName = "movie_cast",
   primaryKeys = ["movieIdMap","castIdMap"],
   foreignKeys = [
       /* A MovieId MUST be a value of an existing id column in the movie table */
       ForeignKey(
           entity = MovieDbModel::class,
           parentColumns = ["id"],
           childColumns = ["movieIdMap"],
           /* Optional (helps maintain referential integrity) */
           /* if parent is deleted then children rows of that parent are deleted */
           onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
           /* if parent column is changed then the column that references the parent is changed to the same value */
           onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
       ),
       ForeignKey(
           entity = CastDbModel::class,
           parentColumns = ["id"],
           childColumns = ["castIdMap"],
           onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
           onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
       )
   ]
)
data class MovieCastCrossRef(
   val movieIdMap: Int,
   @ColumnInfo(index = true)
   val castIdMap: Int
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Cast MUST have a unique **id**, otherwise a conflict will happen. In your case, if the same id is used, due to the use of `OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE` the conflict results in the cast being replaced with the data as per the new Cast.

What you should be doing to insert a new Cast, is to insert the new Cast letting the **id** be generated (by specifying an id of null in the case of AutoGenerate=false), retrieving the generated id e.g. using `fun insertCast (cast: List <CastDbModel>): LongArray`

However, with `val id: Int,` then you cannot specify null. So you should use var id: Int?=null (same for Movie).

Then when you want to add a Cast to a Movie, you insert a MovieCastCrossreference with the movieIdMap as the id from the respective Movie and with castIdMap as the id from the respective Cast.

With some minor changes to your code:-

```
@Entity(tableName = "movie")
data class MovieDbModel(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id: Int?=null, /*<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED to var and default value of null so id can be generated */
    val poster_path: String,
    val overview: String,
    val title: String)

@Entity(tableName = "cast")
@TypeConverters(CastConverter::class)
data class CastDbModel(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id : Int?=null, /*<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED to var and default value of null so id can be generated */
    val cast: Cast
)
```

And with an @Dao annotated Interface :-

```
@Dao
interface AllDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insertMovie(movie: List<MovieDbModel>): LongArray
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insertCast (cast: List <CastDbModel>): LongArray
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insertMovieCastXrossRef(movieCastCrossRef: MovieCastCrossRef): Long

    @Transaction
    @Query("") /* Allows the function to have the @Transaction Applied */
    fun insertCastListForASingleMovie(movieId: Int, castList: List<Int>) {
        for (castId in castList) {
            insertMovieCastXrossRef(MovieCastCrossRef(movieId,castId))
        }
    }
}
```

- note how the Inserts return a value (LongArray for inserting a List, and just Long for a single insert)

using an @Database annotated class (with .allowMainThredQueries for convenience and brevity) name **TheDatabase** and the following code in an activity:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()


        /* Define some Movies */
        val movieList = listOf<MovieDbModel>(
            MovieDbModel(null,"p1","blah1","M1"), /* when run first odds on id will be 1 */
            MovieDbModel(null,"p2","blah2","M2"), /* id likely 2 */
            MovieDbModel(7654,"p3","blah3","M3"), /* id as given i.e 7654 */
            MovieDbModel(null,"p4","blah4","M4"), /* id likely 7655 */
            /* Will very likely NOT BE INSERTED as Movie with id 1 will likely exist */
            MovieDbModel(1,"pOoops","blahOoops","MOoops")
        )
        /* Insert the Movies setting the movieId accordingly from the returned list of inserted id's
            noting that if an insert failed (was ignored i.e. returned id is -1) then a different Log message
         */
        var movieIndex = 0
        for (movieId in dao.insertMovie(movieList)) {
            if (movieId > 0) {
                Log.d("MOVIEINSERT","Movie ${movieList[movieIndex].title} was inserted with an ID of $movieId")

            } else {
                Log.d("MOVIEINSERT","Movie ${movieList[movieIndex].title} insert FAILED due to CONFLICT")
            }
            movieList[movieIndex++].id = movieId.toInt()
        }

        /* Define some CastDBModels */
        val castList = listOf<CastDbModel>(
            CastDbModel(null,Cast("Fred","fredprofile","fred is fred")),
            CastDbModel(null,Cast("Mary","maryprofile","mary is mary")),
            CastDbModel(null, Cast("Anne","anneprofile","anne is anne")),
            CastDbModel(50124,Cast("Tom","tomprofile","tom is tom")),
            CastDbModel(null,Cast("Bert","bertprofile","bert is bert")),
            CastDbModel(null,Cast("Jane","janeprofile","jane is jane")),
            /* Will very likely NOT BE INSERTED as Movie with id 1 will likely exist */
            CastDbModel(1,Cast("Oooops","NOPROFILE","NOCHARACTER"))
        )
        /* Similar to movies */
        val castIdList = dao.insertCast(castList)
        var castIndex = 0
        val castListToUse: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
        for (castId in castIdList) {
            if (castId > 0) {
                Log.d("CASTINSERT","Cast ${castList[castIndex].cast.name} was inserted with an ID of $castId")
                castList[castIndex].id = castId.toInt()
                castListToUse.add(castId.toInt())
            } else {
                Log.d("CASTINSERT","Cast ${castList[castIndex].cast.name} insert Failed")
            }
            castIndex++
        }
        /* Add all the inserted Casts to the 3rd Movie */
        dao.insertCastListForASingleMovie(movieList[3].id!!,castListToUse)
    }
}
```

The the Log Includes :-

```
2022-09-09 11:21:52.778 D/MOVIEINSERT: Movie M1 was inserted with an ID of 1
2022-09-09 11:21:52.778 D/MOVIEINSERT: Movie M2 was inserted with an ID of 2
2022-09-09 11:21:52.778 D/MOVIEINSERT: Movie M3 was inserted with an ID of 7654
2022-09-09 11:21:52.778 D/MOVIEINSERT: Movie M4 was inserted with an ID of 7655
2022-09-09 11:21:52.778 D/MOVIEINSERT: Movie MOoops insert FAILED due to CONFLICT

2022-09-09 11:21:52.832 D/CASTINSERT: Cast Fred was inserted with an ID of 1
2022-09-09 11:21:52.833 D/CASTINSERT: Cast Mary was inserted with an ID of 2
2022-09-09 11:21:52.833 D/CASTINSERT: Cast Anne was inserted with an ID of 3
2022-09-09 11:21:52.833 D/CASTINSERT: Cast Tom was inserted with an ID of 50124
2022-09-09 11:21:52.833 D/CASTINSERT: Cast Bert was inserted with an ID of 50125
2022-09-09 11:21:52.833 D/CASTINSERT: Cast Jane was inserted with an ID of 50126
2022-09-09 11:21:52.833 D/CASTINSERT: Cast Oooops insert Failed
```

- This demonstrates that you can insert with a specific id **IF THE SPECIFIC IS IS UNIQUE* or with a generated id (AutoGenerate does not in fact force/stop auto generation, it just alters how to get generated id's).

To demonstrate the bonus insert an entire CastList to be related to a single Movie. The **movie_cast** table ends up being :-

[image]

- i.e. the 4TH (index 3) movie's id is 7655 so movieIdMap is the same for all rows
- and each castIdMap reflects the castId.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please confirm if I understood it correctly. So instead of one id and cast, there should be id, movie_id, and cast, am I right? And sorry, I didn't get the part about returning Long in the Insert function. I insert cast, autogenerate id and return it, but how can I use it in the insert function? Shouldn't it be used in the @Query function? I thought the insert function just inserts what is needed and doesn't return anything.